# Xcode Version 15.0 beta 2, Info.plist file Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

In my Objective-C MobileApp project, the project was running well in Xcode 14.3. But after upgrading to Xcode 15 beta, I'm getting this issue.

> Info.plist Error Unable to process Info.plist at path /Users/macmini2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileApp-aqrnzgrjfzndxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MobileApp.app/Info.plist

How can I fix this issue?

Here is my CocoaPods Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'MobileApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'BEMCheckBox'
  pod 'QBImagePickerController'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you showing your Podfile? Was your issue resolved with newer versions of Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

In the project settings under Build Phases, try moving "Run Script" (by clicking and dragging) so it is last. [image: Build Phases Screen Shot]

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? How do you know the OP even has a "Run Script" entry? How do you know what might be in it?

Comment: Save my day bro. Move it to the last, then clean and it building fine) I don't know how this is even possible. Very annoying things like that in xcode

Answer (score 1):

Go to Build Phases and play with run scripts, move some of them to the bottom. In my case, I moved the Firebase script to the bottom and the issue disappeared.