# Xcode 15.0.1 Archive Error: Missing CFBundleIdentifier in Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm currently encountering an issue when trying to archive a project using **Xcode 15.0.1**. The error I receive is:

> Required Info.plist Value Not Found. A CFBundleIdentifier value in your Info.plist is required. Please confirm this value is present in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-alueoslszknmrcbcxecexwklitqs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AppName.app/Info.plist`

Might be relevant that I have installed Firebase/Analytics Firebase/Crashlytics using cocoapods

The interesting part is when I build the project and run it directly from **Xcode 15.0.1**, everything works as expected. Additionally, I don't encounter this issue when I try to archive the project using **Xcode 14.3.1**.

Has anyone else faced this issue? How can I resolve this problem?

**What I've tried**:

- Cleaning the project
- Deleting the DerivedData folder
- Archiving with **Xcode 14.3.1** (which works without issues)

**Edit: What I've checked**:

This exists in my Info.plist file

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

Comment: if you look at the file, does it have the missing line?

Comment: No, I see this in the info.plist file:

`<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>`

Comment: Does it appear: (1)  in the `Info.plist` from you project, and/or (2) the file mentioned in the error message (assuming you can see it after the build failure)

Comment: I have this problem with Xcode 15.1 too. I'm not using Cocoapods. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Phases and move script which throws error to the bottom.

Here is screen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77199048/1751321